# How to prove that a convex function $f(x)$ with $f(0) = 0$ satisfes $f'(x)x \ge f(x)$?

Tags: functions, derivatives, convex-analysis

How to prove that a convex function $f(x)$ with $f(0) = 0$ satisfes $f'(x)x > f(x)$?

I am not sure how to use the property of convexity to solve this.

Comment: Use the mean value theorem and the monotonicity of $f'$. Also the inequality is $\ge$, think about $f(x) = x$

Comment: Yes mean value theorem is a good approach here.

Comment: It will also be required to be differentiable of course or $f'(x)$ makes no sense.

Comment: Note that $f'$ is increasing and use https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3008434/42969. Same question for concave functions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/609218/42969.

Comment: The more general inequality holds that $f(x) + (y-x)f'(x)\le f(y)$ if $f$ is convex and differentiable. It amounts to saying that the curve of $f$ is above its tangent line at $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proof uses only the definition of a convex function and existence of $f'(x)$.

If $h>0$ then $x=(t)(0)+(1-t)(x+h)$ where $t =\frac h {x+h}$. Hence $f(x) \leq tf(0)+(1-t) f(x+h)$. I will leave it to you to re-write this inequality as $\frac {f(x+h) -f(x)} h  \geq \frac {f(x)-f(0)} x$. Letting $h \to 0$ gives $f'(x) \geq \frac {f(x)} x$ for  $x>0$. The proof for $x<0$ is similar.

Taking $f\equiv 0$ we see that strict inequality need not hold.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What exactly is $t(0)$? Also I think  $f(x) \leq tf(0)+(1-t) f(x+h)$ can be gotten directly from the convexity of the function, so why "hence"?

Comment: @Aqqqq I meant the product of $t$ and $0$. I have edited the answer to make this clear.

Comment: @Aqqqq I am  getting that inequality from the definition of a convex function. But to apply the definition you have to write $x$ as $(t)(0)+(1-t)(x+h)$.

Answer (score 3):

**Straight-forward approach:**

We are interested in the expression $xf'(x) > f(x) \Leftrightarrow xf'(x) - f(x) > 0$.

In such cases, in Calculus, a good way of working our way is naming a function $F(x) = xf'(x) - f(x)$ be the expression that we are interested in and studying that.

Note that $F'(x) = xf''(x) + f'(x) - f'(x) = xf''(x) > 0 $ for $ x>0$. But, that means that $F(x)$ is an increasing function for $x > 0$. Can you conclude now ?

**Alternative via MVT:**

If $f$ is convex, then $f''(x) > 0$. This means that $f'(x)$ is an increasing function.

Apply the Mean Value Theorem for $f$ now, over an interval $[0,x]$. Then, there exists an element $\xi \in (0,x)$ such that :

$$f'(\xi) = \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} \Leftrightarrow f'(\xi) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$$

But, as we said the function $f'(x)$ is increasing, thus for any $x > \xi$ it is $f'(x) > f'(\xi)$.

That means that $f'(x) > \frac{f(x)}{x} \Leftrightarrow f'(x)x > f(x)$ for $x >0$.

Note that when $x=0$ the strict inequality does not hold, thus : $xf'(x) \geq f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily construct a convex function that is not differentiable and attains $$f(0) = 0$$
The easiest example is probably $f(x) = |x|$ which has derivative everywhere except at $x=0$.

Now to take this one step further, just split line segments (for example already approximating some convex function) into smaller line segments. The derivative will have a jump at every knot between these lines. Now do that systematically, perhaps in a dyadic fashion similar to how discrete wavelets are constructed. You will get a function with as many discontinuities in the derivative as you want.

So your question needs to be attached with the big *IF it is differentiable*.